# Django form with many-to-many relationship does not save

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a custom registration form for my users to add a profile on my app. However, a bug has recently popped up in that the form is not saving the information that is put into all the fields.

My user model, `MyUser` has a ManyToMany relationship with another model, `Interest`, and this is where the issues are arising. I am not sure if it is the `RegistrationForm` or the `register` view that is causing it, so I have included both below, as well as the model code.
I also have a view for the users to update their profile, also included, once it is created, and this is working absolutely perfectly. This is the `personal` view.
As I say, it is only the `Interest` field that is not being returned, even though it is being filled in on the registration page.

Any help or advice is much appreciated, thanks.

**models.py**

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
                        verbose_name='email address',
                        max_length=255,
                        unique=True,
                    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/friends/home/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    template = "adduser.html"
    data = { 'form': form, }
    return render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required(login_url='/friends/login/')
def personal(request):
    """
    Personal data of the user profile
    """
    profile = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _("Your profile information has been updated successfully."))
            return redirect('/friends/success/')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

    template = "update_profile.html"
    data = { 'section': 'personal', 'form': form, }
    return render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password (again)")
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.order_by('title'))
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.order_by('location'))

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'course',
            'location',
            'interests',
            'bio',
            ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):#Sort interests alphabetically
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['interests'].queryset = Interest.objects.order_by('title')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match. Please enter again.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you use `commit=false` for the `super(RegistrationForm, self).save` call, it doesn't save the many-to-many field. You therefore need to add `self.save_m2m()` after `user.save()` in your `save()` method of `RegistrationForm`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

EDIT: `save_m2m()` is on the Form, not the Model

Comment: up for `save_m2m() is on the Form` :)