# In my Django form I'm not able to save a tag to a newly created post

Tags: python, django

I have created a form that is directly linked to my Post model. I cancreate and save a post. But for some reason I can't save a tag to a post unless I go into the django admin. Heres my code:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = [
        "title",
        "content",
        "image",
        "draft",
        "publish",
        "tags",
    ]
```

models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils import timezone



class Post(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True,
                            width_field="width_field",
                            height_field="height_field")
  height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  content = models.TextField()
  draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

  objects = PostManager()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

  class Meta:
      ordering = ["-timestamp"]


class Tag(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("posts:tag_index", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

  class Meta:
      ordering = ["-timestamp"]
```

post_form.html

```
{% extends "posts/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <h1>Edit: {{ title }}</h1>



    <form method='post' action=''  enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create Post">
    </form>

    <a href="{% url 'posts:list' %}">cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}}
```

my views.py:

```
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()

        messages.success(request, "Created !!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "not Created !!")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "title": "Create Form"
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_form.html", context)
```

any help or advice in the right direction is welcomed.

Comment: What's your view for this?

Comment: @ShangWang I just added it

Comment: Where in your views did you save a `tag` to a `post`?

Comment: Have you tried it without the crispy tag to see if that works?

Comment: @jcfollower just tried that and still nothing

Comment: So, is the form input valid and it saves everything except the tags?

Comment: Is this the answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057512/django-form-with-many-to-many-relationship-does-not-save

Answer (score 0):

To use tags, I recommend [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html).  It's very simple to use.