# How to add default value in queryset?

Tags: django

I have a moneybook, moneylog models

and moneylog get relation with moneybook manytomany.

```
moneybook = models.ForeignKey(
    moneybook_models.Moneybook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pay_day = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)
payer = models.ForeignKey(
    user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="payer")
dutch_payer = models.ManyToManyField(
    user_models.User, related_name="dutch_payer", blank=True)
price = models.IntegerField()
category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
memo = models.TextField()
```

I want payer default save in dutch_payer if user choose or not.

and this is my **forms.py**

```
class CreateMoneylogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Moneylog
        fields = (
            "pay_day",
            "payer",
            "dutch_payer",
            "price",
            "category",
            "memo",
        )
        widgets = {
            "dutch_payer": forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        moneylog = super().save(commit=False)
        return moneylog
```

**views.py**

```
class moneylog_create(FormView):

    form_class = forms.CreateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save()
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        form.instance.moneybook = moneybook
        if moneylog.payer not in moneylog.dutch_payer.all():
            moneylog.dutch_payer.add(moneylog.payer)
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("cores:home"))
```

as you see.

```
    if moneylog.payer not in moneylog.dutch_payer.all():
        moneylog.dutch_payer.add(moneylog.payer)
    moneylog.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect(reverse("cores:home"))
```

this not work.(there is no payer in dutch_payer) how can i achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django form with many-to-many relationship does not save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057512/django-form-with-many-to-many-relationship-does-not-save)

Comment: thanks for reply, but the saving is work, but moneylog.dutch_payer.add(moneylog.payer) doesn't work. i tried save_m2m but also doesn't work.